# Gridelements, Attempt to insert record on page '[root-level]' (0) where this table, tt_content, is not allowed

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-11.x

I installed the current Typo3 Version 11 and implemented Gridelements first in Version 10 (stable) and testwise in version 11 (beta). In both versions, i get the error:

> Attempt to insert record on page '[root-level]' (0) where this table,
> tt_content, is not allowed

and

> Attempt to move record 'mxText' (tt_content:16) without having
> permissions to insert.

I don't know whats wrong.
But it only happens after Drag&Drop. Creating an Element directly inside works fine.
In TYPO3 version 10 everything works fine.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Gridelements is not officially available for TYPO3 CMS 11 yet. So you should expect the current repository version - even dev-master - to still throw several errors.

There is a crowdfunding campaign though, to provide the necessary milestones, which are

1. Fluid Based Page Module
2. Basic CMS 11 compatibility
3. Make it run with PHP 8

so you might either want to support that campaign or you will have to wait until Gridelements 11.x will be made available.

I'm not sure if it is allowed to post the link to that campaign here though.

Comment: no update on this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/gridelements and get your `ZIP` file of the official `11.0.0` release now, or make use of the composer require line there, or update your extension list in the backend, in case you are not on composer yet.